# How to set value in array of array index

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [a31df20a1e75a9200fc0d8b136438c91] => Array
        (
            [addons] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Add Message here, First 5 Words Free
                            [value] => tyyty tytyt ty
                            [price] => 10
                        )

                )

            [product_id] => 1356
            [variation_id] => 
            [variation] => 
            [quantity] => 1
            [line_total] => 110
            [line_tax] => 0
            [line_subtotal] => 110
            [line_subtotal_tax] => 0
        )

)
```

how can i set value of "[line_total] => 110"?

Comment: The poster has not tried anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$thearray['a31df20a1e75a9200fc0d8b136438c91']['line_total'] = 110;
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the path to the value, so you can just set it..

```
$array['a31df20a1e75a9200fc0d8b136438c91']['line_total'] = 12345;
```